# What is the equals sign followed by tilde in lighttpd config (=~)?

Tags: lighttpd

What is the difference between the following? Both work the same way from what I can tell/use it for

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "a.domain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/a/"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "a.domain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/a/"
}
```

Would the `=~` match `x.a.domain.com`?

Comment: From http://thomashunter.name/blog/subdomains-and-google-apps-with-gandi-and-linode/ *"The lighttpd configuration file uses a proprietary syntax (although it kinda looks like a cross between PHP and JSON). The Tilde Equal lines are a regular expression which match the requested domain name and apply the rules within that section."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side of `=~` is a regular expression.

`x.a.domain.com` would not match the regular expression `a.domain.com`.

Examples that would match:

- `axdomain.com`
- `axdomainxcom`
- `aydomainycom`
- `a1domain1com`
- ...

Is the example from a real-world example? It seems kinda pointless.

Something like this could be more meaningful:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*\.somedomain\.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/somedomain.com/"
}
```

Meaning, serve all requests to *.somedomain.com from `/var/www/somedomain.com/`

This page has some more realistic examples with regex matching:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/2518